# What is the intuition behind the `Glue` type in Cubical Type Theories

Tags: type-theory, cubical-type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalence

I have some clues regarding `Glue` based on a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02108.pdf) and the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337390/glue-types-in-cubical-type-theory).

The first resource says that `Glue` "glues together" a partial and total types along a partial equivalence between them. Hm, okay, let's carry on.

The second resource references the fact that `Glue` extends a partial `Σ(:) (≃)` to total one. This is in line with the fact that univalence, the theorem `Glue` was devised for, is itself equivalent to `Σ(:) (≃)` being contractible which is, AFAIU, equivalent (in the Cubical setting) to asking that every partial `Σ(:) (≃)` can be extended to a total one. The last condition seems to be very similar to what `Glue` does, but I still don't see the full picture. Also I don't understand the intuition behind elements of `Glue`, i.e. `glue` and elimination of `Glue`, i.e. `unglue` whatsoever.

Comment: In CCHM section 6.1, they have the typing & computation rules for `glue` and `unglue`.

Comment: I understand the typing and computation rules. But that unfortunately doesn't help me with intuition...

Answer (score 4):

I would say Glue types are the "in-between" part of a path equality. For instance, take the Booleans. We can construct a type
$$\mathsf{Glue}^i_{\color{brown}{\mathbb B}}\begin{cases}
(i=0) \Rightarrow \mathbb B, \color{blue}{\mathrm{id}}\\
(i=1) \Rightarrow \mathbb B, \color{red}{\mathrm{not}}.
\end{cases}$$
The picture of this type goes roughly like this:

[image: 1]
The reason that these lines can be drawn is that you provided a way to align all the parts to $\mathbb B$, the "anchor-type" at the bottom-right corner of $\mathsf{Glue}_{\mathbb B}^i$. The constructor $\mathsf{glue}$ creates the gray points by providing an element of the anchor type. The deconstructor does the opposite.

[image]

The blue arrows denote the equivalence $\mathrm{id}$, and the red arrows the equivalence $\mathrm{not}$. Therefore, $\mathsf{glue}$ will follow the arrows: $\mathsf{glue}^i(\mathsf{true})$ will give the line connecting the lower left and upper right, etc.

Comment: What is a "part"? What does it mean to "align a part"?
It seems to me that the total type `` (the argument of `Glue` located at the bottom) is not drawn in the picture. The left and right vertical lines in the picture are partial ``. What would be the two values inside `glue` that create the upper grey dot?
What is the intuition behind those two values?

Comment: @Russoul Updated.

Comment: `id` shall exist only when `i = 0` and `not` only when `i = 1`.
So I would expect the rectangles containing blue lines and red lines be perpendicular to the `i` axis. But they are not... I am confused.

Comment: @Russoul They are triangles sticking into the third dimension. Unfortunately your screen is two dimensional, so I can't draw into that. Also, the arrows are not paths. They only signify a correspondence.

Comment: Additionally, the isomorphisms don't have `i` coordinates. They are not in the coordinate system at all, overseeing everything else. If there are `i,j` coordinates, then the anchor type would be the top of a pyramid, overseeing the square.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think they are triangles. I am pretty sure they are rectangles :P
You can use dashed lines to present a 3D shape on 2D space unambiguously.
I find it counter-intuitive to present the `id` and `not` equivalences as lines laying on a 2D space not perpendicular to i-axis. So I don't think the pyramid is the right shape here.

Comment: @Russoul They are correctly represented as triangles (or more generally pyramids with a n-dimensional cube as the bottom; triangles are the n=1 case, ordinary pyramids are the n=2 case). I do not understand why you think this is not the right shape.